# If I have obj_id (table), file_id, block and row, how can I query the actual data row from table?

Tags: oracle

If I update same data row from 2 sessions and don't commit, then run query from the 3rd session:

```
select row_wait_obj#, row_wait_file#, row_wait_block#, row_wait_row#
from v$session where lockwait is not null;
```

I'll see the blocked session pending on:

```
row_wait_obj#    row_wait_file# row_wait_block#  row_wait_row#
----------       ----------     ----------       ----------
       258          1           2082             0
```

Suppose `row_wait_obj#=258` is a table. How can I see the actual data row where contention happened?

Comment: Please [edit] the question and include details of how you generated that data (did you `SELECT` it from the data dictionary? Or use functions? If so which?). The `OBJECT_ID` pseudo-column does not generate a numeric value like that ([fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/EVUVg-5j)) so seeing how you generate the data may help with reversing the process.

Comment: You can find the table with a data dictionary query such as: `SELECT OWNER, OBJECT_NAME FROM DBA_OBJECTS WHERE OBJECT_ID = 258;` Then you can narrow down the data to the block by using the procedures in the package [DBMS_ROWID](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/DBMS_ROWID.html). I think ROW=0 means the actual row number was not recorded. If you edit this question and add details and explain why you need this, hopefully this question will be re-opened and I can add a fuller answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Columns like ROW_WAIT_OBJ#, ROW_WAIT_FILE#, ROW_WAIT_BLOCK#, and ROW_WAIT_ROW# can be converted into the actual data row by using a combination of data dictionary queries and used to find the actual data and the [DBMS_ROWID](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/DBMS_ROWID.html) package.

The exact values posted in the question cannot be replicated, since they depend on many system-specific details. But the below example demonstrates how to find the data for a similar situation.

Create a table and open up two separate sessions. One sessions will update a row, and the other session will try to update the same row but will be blocked and have to wait for the first session to finish.

```
-- Create a simple table with 100K rows.
create table table1(a number);
insert into table1 select level from dual connect by level <= 100000;
commit;

-- Session #1: Update one row in the middle of the table to a negative number;
update table1 set a = -50000 where a = 50000;

-- Session #2: Waits until session #1 is committed or rolled back.
update table1 set a = -12345 where a = 50000;
```

That waiting second session will now show up in the data dictionary:

```
select row_wait_obj#, row_wait_file#, row_wait_block#, row_wait_row#
from v$session where lockwait is not null;


ROW_WAIT_OBJ#   ROW_WAIT_FILE#   ROW_WAIT_BLOCK#   ROW_WAIT_ROW#
-------------   --------------   ---------------   -------------
       137247               12             91565             499
```

Find the table name with this query. As expected, the table name is the table we just created.

```
select * from dba_objects where object_id = 137247;

OBJECT_NAME
---
TABLE1
```

Find the ROWID, which is like a physical pointer to the relevant row, using DBMS_ROWID:

```
select dbms_rowid.rowid_create(rowid_type    => 1 /* restricted rowid */,
                               object_number => 137247,
                               relative_fno  => 12,
                               block_number  => 91565,
                               row_number    => 499) the_rowid
from dual;

THE_ROWID
---------
AAAhgfAAMAAAWWtAHz
```

Finally, use the ROWID to query the individual row that was changed:

```
select * from table1 where rowid = 'AAAhgfAAMAAAWWtAHz';

A
-----
50000
```

### This approach may not work perfectly for this specific case

While the above code answers your question in most cases, it looks like you have an unusual issue. Your low OBJECT_ID of 258 implies the waits are for a system-owned object. And the ROW_WAIT_ROW# of 0 implies that the wait is not based on a row, and it is either a DDL wait or a SELECT wait. Performance "wait events", such as the time it might take to read from a block, appear in GV$ACTIVE_SESSION_HISTORY with CURRENT_ROW# of 0, and I would guess the same thing is happening here.

You'll probably need to investigate your problem a different way. You'll still want to start with querying DBA_OBJECTS, but then you might need to find the the relevant sessions by querying GV$SESSION, then find the SQL_IDs, confirm that the SQL_IDs are really slow by looking at GV$ACTIVE_SESSION_HISTORY (each row represents one second of waiting time, so if only pay attention to statements with many rows of waiting), then look up the relevant statements in GV$SQL. You may still need a lot of troubleshooting to get to the bottom of this issue.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, exactly what I needed. Don't worry about the object_id here, it is a random number I put in. Appreciated the details provided.